# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForPlayDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForPlayDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list D:\Android_Project\prayer-times-android-master\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\play\debug\maindexlist.txt --output D:\Android_Project\prayer-times-android-master\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\play\debug\folders\1000\1f\main D:\Android_Project\prayer-times-android-master\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\play\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}**

build.gradle(Module App)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } //excludeInFDroid
    }

    dependencies {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:+' //excludeInFDroid
    }


}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'  //excludeInFDroid

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debugKey {
            storeFile file('D:/TU-Cloud/Dokumente/Sonstiges/debug.keystore')
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.metinkale.prayer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debugKey
        versionCode 189
        versionName '3.6.5'
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        preDexLibraries = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugKey
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        fdroid {
            versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + " F-Droid"
        }
        play {
            versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + " Play Store"
            repositories {
                maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } //excludeInFDroid
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}





dependencies {
    playCompile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {//excludeInFDroid
        transitive = true;//excludeInFDroid
    }    //excludeInFDroid
    fdroidCompile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.8.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'com.vanniktech:vntnumberpickerpreference:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6:no-tzdb'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.anrwatchdog:anrwatchdog:1.3.0'
    playCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'    //excludeInFDroid
    playCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'    //excludeInFDroid
    playCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'    //excludeInFDroid
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add multiDexEnabled as true in defaultConfig.

Comment: Try to add the dependency: 
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html says if you define your minSdkVersion lower than 20, you have to add the dependency.

Comment: already try, don't work

Comment: Did you try "4g" instead of "2g"?

Comment: yes i also try 4g

Comment: @Prexx is there is JDK isuue ?!

Comment: becz i have jdk 1.8  and in  gradle 1.7

Comment: Does you application class extends `MultiDexApplication` class? Also make  sure you have compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' in your dependencies.